# Wordpress admin-ajax.php now longer works what has changed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am having issues with some of our users saying they have upgraded or changed theme and then they can no longer access our api.

For instance this user.
http://mindfulnessexercises.com/nature-sounds-woodland-bridalway/

See the spinning audio player this is their question.

> We recently changed our theme to “Headline News,” and found out that the audio shortcode seemed to be not working any more. We are sure that the file from Amazon S3 is working and is in public just like how it’s working using your plugin before.

I cannot understand what has changed and why this may no longer be working for them has Wordpress changed anything with the admin-ajax.php file with the new update.

With my plugin i am doing the following.

```
var sendData = {
    "action": "internal_ajax",
    "Data" : "Data goes here"
}
$.post("' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '", sendData, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, 'json');
```

PHP

```
function internal_ajax() {

    //set POST variables
    $url = 'https://api.s3bubble.com/main_plugin/single_audio_object';
    $response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'sslverify' => true,
        'timeout' => 10,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(),
        'body' => array(
            'data' => $_POST['Data']
        ),
        'cookies' => array()
    ));

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {

        $error_message = $response - > get_error_message();
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                "error" => true,
                "message" => $error_message
            )
        );
    } else {

        echo $response['body'];

    }

    wp_die();

}

add_action('wp_ajax_internal_ajax', array($this, 'internal_ajax'));
```

Has anything changed i am so stuck on how to bug test this because i can set it up on another host provider and i will work fine no issue at all.

Can anyone suggest how i can bug test this, would really really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: is that all they have reported? have they given wordpress version, plugin version, browser vendor and version etc?? somethign must have changed, has your plugin been updated? hae they updated wordpress? the video file? have they moved servers/domain?? has anyone else reported this?